# Xamarin forms: Open browser and start searching a keyword saved in local db

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using following code for opening google from my xamarin forms app.

```
 Device.OpenUri(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

I am also saving a string in my local DB using the following code.

```
 Application.Current.Properties["MyIP"] = mystring;
```

I want to open the browser and search this keyword automatically.
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the search query to google in the URL:

```
var mySearchQuery = Application.Current.Properties["MyIP"]?.ToString();
Device.OpenUri(new Uri($"https://www.google.com/search?q={mySearchQuery}"));
```